# How can I make a CSS triangle the same height as it's parent element?

Tags: css

I'm trying to match this layout here:
[image]

I want one section with an equal split.  The left side has a background color and the other does not.  This issue I'm running into is that I want the triangle that is attached to the left side the SAME height as the element itself.  If I give it a set height then additional/newer content will throw this off.  How can I make this happen?  Here is what I'm working with:

```
<section class='panel panel--standard u-bgColorSplitForm service-cta'>
    <div class="container">
        <?php if (have_rows('service_cta_group')) :
            while (have_rows('service_cta_group')) : the_row();
                $kicker = get_sub_field('kicker');
                $headline = get_sub_field('headline');
                $copy =  get_sub_field('copy');
                $form_header = get_sub_field('form_header');
                $form_id = get_sub_field('form_id');
        ?>
                <div class="grid">
                    <div class="grid__col--6 split-left">
                        <h4><?php echo $kicker; ?></h4>
                        <h3><?php echo $headline; ?></h3>
                        <p><?php echo $copy; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid__col--6">
                        <!-- Form will be added here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile;
        endif; ?>
</section>

.service-cta {
  position: relative;
  h4 {
    font-family: $font-stack-secondary;
    font-style: italic;
  }
  h3 {
    font-weight: 400;
  }
}

.split-left {
  position: relative;
  // triangle
  &::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -100px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-top: 120px solid transparent;
    border-left: 75px solid $color-primary-tint;
    border-bottom: 120px solid transparent;
    transition: $transition-base;

    @include create-mq($md-width) {
      border-top: 150px solid transparent;
      border-left: 100px solid $color-primary-tint;
      border-bottom: 150px solid transparent;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused what you mean by "I want the triangle that is attached to the left side the SAME height as the element itself" Isn't the triangle on the right and the left side is background color? Is the picture you attached the right orientation?

Comment: Yes, it is to the right of the side with the bg color, but the way I'm thinking about it the triangle belongs to the left side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is messy trying to paint a triangle using borders.

Modern browsers have a clip-path property. We can use that to clip the chevron shape out of a pseudo element. If we use a polygon with % positioning of the vertices it will automatically adjust to any alteration in the dimensions of the element.

Here is a simple example in pure CSS:

```css
.chevron {
  position: relative;
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 20vmin;
  border: solid 1px black;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* note this bg put in to stop 1 screen pixel white lines appearing at some zoom levels */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 0 50%, transparent 50% 100%);
}

.chevron::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 60% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="chevron"></div>
```